# Applications require accessibility access when using keyboard shortcut created with automator macOS Big Sur

Tags: keyboard, automator, shortcut, accessibility

I made a keyboard shortcut through automator. However, using the keyboard shortcut with any other app open in the background requires that application is granted accessibility access in system preferences. This is annoying, as I would have to do this for every application that I use this shortcut for, and also might maybe possibly be a security risk.

Any way around this?

Comment: Prior to **macOS Big Sur** I used [FastScripts](https://redsweater.com/fastscripts/) to trigger my **AppleScript** _keyboard shortcuts_ because after approving it the first time it didn't need separate confirmation for each _application_. I have not tested this in **macOS Big Sur** yet but maybe it's worth looking at. It's free for up to 10 _keyboard shortcuts_. I'm not affiliated with the developer of this _application_.